# Needs to mock beans in integration test case

Tags: java, google-api, testng, spring-batch, jakarta-mail

I am writing an integration test case by using testng for spring batch job. In my application, I am using Google API for address and Mail Sender to send the email. In my integration test case, it takes time during a test run for connection and at the end send exception which looks ugly and time-consuming.

I tried to mock the beans but I don't know how to do exactly in an integration test case.

```
Google Api Code:

@Slf4j
public final class GoogleApiContext {

    private static GeoApiContext context;

    private GoogleApiContext() {
    }

    public static GeoApiContext getGeoApiContext(String apiKey, int maxQps) {

        if (context == null) {
            log.info("Creating google api context having key - {} and maxQps - {}", apiKey, maxQps);
            context = new GeoApiContext.Builder().apiKey(apiKey).queryRateLimit(maxQps).build();
        }

        return context;
    }

}

Mail Sender Code:

@Override
    public Boolean sendMailWithAttachment(final MailBo mailBo, final String pathToAttachment, final String fileName) {
        try {
            log.info("Sending Email {}", mailBo);
            MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
            MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);
            helper.setTo(mailBo.getTo());
            helper.setSubject(mailBo.getSubject());
            helper.setText(mailBo.getText());
            File file = new File(pathToAttachment);
            helper.addAttachment(fileName, file);
            mailSender.send(message);
            log.info("Mail sent successfully");
            return true;

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            log.info("Mail Exception {}", e);
            return false;
        }
    }

Integration Test Case:

@SpringBootTest(
    classes = {ApplicationLauncher.class, BatchConfiguration.class, BatchTestConfig.class})
public class PostalJobTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

  @Autowired
  private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

  @Autowired
  JobLauncher dataloadJobLauncher;

  @Autowired
  private Job postalJob;

  @Test
  public void testPostalJob_valid_response() throws Exception {
    String fileName = getFileName(FileLocation.POSTAL_VALID, FileLocation.TEMP_POSTAL_VALID);
    JobParametersBuilder jobParametersBuilder = getJobParametersBuilder(fileName);
    jobLauncherTestUtils.setJob(postalJob);
    jobLauncherTestUtils.setJobLauncher(dataloadJobLauncher);
    JobExecution jobExecution =
        jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob(jobParametersBuilder.toJobParameters());
    Assert.assertEquals(jobExecution.getStatus(), BatchStatus.STARTING);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    while (jobExecution.isRunning()) {
    }
    Assert.assertEquals(jobExecution.getStatus(), BatchStatus.COMPLETED);


  }
```

I want to mock GeoApiContext and MailSender for integration test case and if I can create a dummy server to achieve the response so that test runs faster without any exception. Please help me out.

Comment: Try using spring @MockBean annotation: Official docs:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/MockBean.html

Comment: is it possible to mock beans in an integration test case

Answer (score 1):

In an integration test case, there is no direct way to mock beans. So the alternate solution is to make the setter injection in your application and In your test case change that bean.

```
  // mail service
  private JavaMailSender mailSender;

  @Autowired
  public void setMailSender(JavaMailSender mailSender) {
    this.mailSender = mailSender;
  }


  // test file

  @Autowired
  private MailServiceImpl mailService;

  @BeforeClass
  public void setJob() {
    jobLauncherTestUtils.setJob(postalJob);
    mailService.setMailSender(new JavaMailSenderTestImpl());
  }
```